# Hiding dialer when making a call from app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an android app to control an electrical circuit via gsm. This app sends a signal as a call or msg to a gsm module connected to an electrical circuit that will break the circuit according to the signal received. What i want is when i click a button in the activity, a gsm call should be made to a particular number which is written in code, **but should not invoke the dialer ui** .the dialer ui needs to be replaced with some progress image for some seconds. anyone please help me. I completed all the electrical and electronics circuits for this project, but stuck here. Please help.

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.orveehomes"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.orveehomes.main" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

main.java

```
package com.orveehomes;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class main extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void call(View view) {
      Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
 }
}
```

main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/white" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/orvee1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/orvee1" />
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/btnname" 
       android:onClick="call" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: i didn't understand. i am developing app for any android device. so what's special in rooting.

Comment: You can't hide the dialer on a standard Android device. Rooting is about the only way it might be possible.

Comment: can i use some other activity to come up instead of dialer by setting up a new intent?

Comment: Accessing the actual phone functionality on an Android device is a tightly controlled process, due to security concerns. You can create your own dialer, but you can't really control anything after the call is initiated, so you're always going to see the call-in-progress screen.